# Extract file length from output of 'ls -l' passed back from sftp session

Tags: files, grep, string, sftp

From my local server I only have access to stfp to a remote server where I want to check the size of my backup file as it's being created. So I've been able to write a bit of bash that logs in and issues an 'ls -l' command:

```
file_listing=$(sftp connection_string:Path/to <<<$'ls -l file.sql.gz')
```

...which produces:

```
$ echo $file_listing
Changing to: /Path/to sftp> ls -l file.sql.gz -rw------- ? 19009 19009 7834147822 Oct 19 23:02 file.sql.gz
```

And I want to be able to use either bash native string manipulation or grep or something just to extract the file size part of that string. In this case the `7834147822`

I've tried grepping, and egrepping for a pattern

```
size_pattern='([0-9]{1} {1}[0-9]+ {1}[A-Z]{1})'
```

or doing...

```
echo $file_listing  | egrep -o '[[:digit:]]\{1\}[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]\+[[:blank:]][A-Z]\{1\}'
```

...or something. I realise that would give me "`9 7834147822 O`" if it worked, but I reckon even I can manage string manipulation to strip one character and one space from either end before using it as a file size.

Does that make sense? Anyone got some thoughts?

Best wishes, Jock Coats

Comment: I tried stat on the remote sftp command line and got command not found. Nor can I break out into an ssh session. And I don't even think paramiko will work because I seemed to understand that it started with an ssh session before spawning an sfto session so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, if you only have sftp you can't run `stat`, that's why I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't quote your variable with `echo`, it all is printed in one line. Put quotes, and it will be easier for you to `grep`.

However, I would still prefer `awk`:

```bash
echo "$file_listing"  | awk 'NR==3{print $5}'
```

---

Another interesting approach using `set`:

```
set -- $(tail -n1 <<< "$file_listing")
echo $5
```

---

Note, instead of parsing `ls -l`, it would be better to use `stat` if you have access via `ssh`, not only `sftp`:

```bash
ssh user@server 'stat --format %s /path/to/file'
```

Comment: TBH I was trying to stick with grep just because I didn't fancy grokking another "language" in the form of awk. But that works beautifully, thank you - apparently I can't yet give an uptick but it deserves one.

Comment: I think there's only one line, not 3. It was your (helpful!) edit that made it look like three lines.

Comment: @JockCoats wait, you have three lines in the `$file_listing` variable? Also, if this worked for you, you can  [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: `Changing to ...` , `> sftp` and the result are three lines in the variable. I checked that... ;-)

Comment: Can we pelase edit the question to show that then? Otherwise it's a bit confusing.

Comment: But that is part of the problem because OP omitted the quotes, it shows all in only 1 line!

Comment: Remember what is returned is the whole record of the albeit short sftp session...so yeah, "Changing to: /Path/to ", "sftp> ls -l file.sql.gz " and then the results of the ls -l are all in the variable. I hadn't noticed they were on different lines and can probably improve it somehow by only putting the last line of the output into the $file_listing variable

Comment: Fair. I added the `$` to indicate that the `echo` is the command, at least.

Comment: While surely possible, I don't see any **good** way to do it with `grep`, it is simply the wrong tool. Learning at least some basic `awk` is very useful!

Comment: Yeah...I was running scared of it. Will try and grok it a bit more now I know it looks so easy! :) The various cheat sheets didn't look that way.

Comment: May I ask a bit of a follow up or should I put it in another question: I notice that if I login on the command line to the sftp server and do an `ls -l` at the sftp prompt I get a remote server time on the file, whereas if I issue this entire command `file_listing=$(sftp connection_string:Path/to <<<$'ls -l file.sql.gz')` as in the question it gives me it in my local client time. Surely I'm doing the exact same set of commands just all in one rather than interactively? I don't mind which time I get (local or server) as long as I know!

Comment: This should be a new question I think. You can refer to this question there. However, if my answer helped you, you can click the checkmark next to it to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not like `awk`, you can use a combination of standard tools:

These two commands are equivalent:

```
echo "$file_listing"  | awk 'NR==3{print $5}'
echo "$file_listing"  | head -n3 | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f5
```

- `head` and `tail` will print first 3 lines, and just last line of the these three.
- `tr` will squeeze all repeated spaces and replace them with a tab.
- And the `cut` will print 5th word.

Answer (score 0):

AWK is your friend here. AWK will look at a line of text and separate it into columns based on the white space it encounters. Each one of those columns has a numeric place holder $1, $2, etc. On my machine `ls -l` produces 9 columns, and this command will get what you need.

`ls -l file.sql.gz | awk '{print $5}'`

If you want the human readable size in K / MB / GB use `ls -lh`

In your example the line of text also contains info like 'Changing to: ...' You can see the entire line that AWK is receiving with `awk '{print $NF}'` and then simply count the columns until you get to the one you're looking for.

Comment: TBH I was trying to stick with grep just because I didn't fancy grokking another "language" in the form of awk. And, just to note, I can't send that command string as one to the sftp session - I need to send ls -l to the sftp and then get its output into the local buffer on the machine from which I'm running the command. But when I do it as pLumbo suggests below on the returned string it works perfectly.

Comment: It is best to put the code in code formatted blocks. It looks like you started with the \` before ls, but you need one at the end also.